# Magento 2 - How can I set the image url for a category?

Tags: category, image

Magento 2 - How can I set the image url for a category? Programatically, not through admin, off course.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean set "image url"? Category image is saved in an attribute `image` in catalog_category_entity_varchar table. Programatically you can set this attribute on a category providing a path to the file relative from `$MAGE_ROOT/pub/media/catalog/category` folder.

You can set this like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
 */
$category->setImage($relativePath);
$category->getResource()->saveAttribute($category, 'image');
```

Comment: And how can I programaticaly set this?